# Django MultipleHiddenInput and ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-forms

Can a ManyToManyField inside a ModelForm use a forms.MultipleHiddenInput widget instead of the default forms.MultipleChoiceField? In the example below 'groups' is a ManyToManyField on the Model 'Test':

```
class TestSelectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('groups')
        widgets = {
          'groups': forms.MultipleHiddenInput()
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestSelectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['groups'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(...)
```

But no hidden input fields were rendered for this form. Am I missing something or is it just not possible to use MultipleHiddenInput together with a ManyToManyField? (Should I then just write the HTML for the hidden inputs inside the template or is there a different approach I could use from within the ModelForm)?